# How do I rename a volume in the Disks utility - in 18.04?

Tags: partitioning

I clicked the gear icon/ edit mount options but don't know which field changes the actual label for the volume that shows upon my desktop visually.

Answer (score 2):

To change the filesystem label do the following:

1. Open GNOME Disks (`gnome-disks`)
2. Select partition with mouse
3. Unmount it by clicking on *Unmount selected partition* ([image: unmount])
4. Click on *Additional partition options* ([image: options])
5. Select *Edit filesystem*

   [image: label]
6. Specify the *Label*
7. Click *Change*
8. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks!! I was simply not unmounting it first. 

Problem solved!

Comment: Great so you can accept this answer :)